# jQuery onclick POST does not get through

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do a POST whenever a button is clicked.
However, it's not working properly and I'm not sure why.
Do I have to put it in a ?

HTML:

```
            <form>
                <button type="submit" id="add"> Add</button>
            </form>
```

Script:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


$( "#add" ).click(function() {
    var info= {username: "alex",
               type:"friend"
              }


$.post('localhost:3000/info', info);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

in $.post method second parameter is a call back must use function here i made some change tell me if it will solve your problem

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


$( "#add" ).click(function() {
    var info= {username: "alex",
               type:"friend"
              }


$.post('localhost:3000/info', function(info, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});

});
```

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp) is a link for more info

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, just refresh the page. I'm going insane, I tried ob submit too

Comment: try after removing <form action="/action_page.php" method="get"> if you are using those attribute

Comment: I don't have those attributes. It's just plain <form>. I do have multiple forms, they're not encapsulated in one another

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ulrichdohou/pen/jKaBZv?editors=1011). First parameter is the URL, the second one is the JSON data and the third is the callback. But you can have two parameters. In that case the second one is the callback. It means you are not sending any data to the server. Also you should use for your tag button `button` type instead of `submit`.
Code is bellow too.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <button type="button" id="add"> Add</button>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#add" ).on('click', function() {
  $.post('http://localhost:3000/info', {username: "alex",type:"friend"}, function(result){
    console.log('sucsess',result);
    alert( "first success" );
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
});
```